# Django REST zip file download return empty zip

Tags: python, django, download, django-rest-framework, zip

I'm writing a script to download a zip file. I read a lot around on how to do this, but i still got some troubles. As you can see in the code, I first create a tempfile, write data on it, then zip it and download. The problem is the result: a zip archive with an empty file inside. This is the code:

```
    f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    f.write(html.encode('utf-8')) 
    print(f.read) #the "writing of tmp file" seem to work, the expected output is right

    fzip = ZipFile("test.zip","w")
    fzip.write(f.name,'exercise.html') #this file remains empty

    response = HttpResponse(fzip, content_type="application/zip")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; "filename=test.zip"'
    return response
```

I already tried to set NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) or to seek(0) and stuff like that. I think the problem is the fzip.write, but actually I can't figure other solutions, can anyone help? 
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create a buffer to write the zipfile into
zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()

# Create the zipfile, giving the buffer as the target
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, 'w') as zip_file:
    f.seek(0)
    zip_file.write(html.encode('utf-8'),'exercise.html')
    f.close()

response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/x-zip-compressed')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=test.zip'
# Write the value of our buffer to the response
response.write(zip_buffer.getvalue())

return response
```

Comment: Can u explain a little why are you using io.BytesIO() ?
p.s. u missed something in this reply (fzip.write doesn't work, clearly) but i will try anyway this solution

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I fixed this and added a few comment.

Comment: Btw, this way the response give back an OSError:
 [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n  <meta charset="UTF-8">\n  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">\n  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"content="ie=edge">\n  <title>Document</title> etc..etc..

Comment: Now I'm re-reading my answer and I don't get why you might need the `NamedTemporaryFile` (The source of your error). Edited my answer.

Comment: I figured out, I didn't used io.BytesIo(), the solution is much like the code in my first question, but now it works, many thanks for help :)